# Using DEFRA LiDAR dtm-1m to calculate slopes etc in QGIS

Tags: dem, contour, slope, gdal-contour

I have a shapefile of woodland polygons and want to calulate slope and slope orientation of the polygons.

I am using the LiDAR Composite Digital Terrain Model (DTM) - 1m in QGIS. Available at: https://environment.data.gov.uk/dataset/13787b9a-26a4-4775-8523-806d13af58fc I have tried importing it as WMS and WCS.

When I run the slope tool in the processing toolbox, or the GDAL contours tool I get this error so I think I am missing something.

> ERROR 4: `contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=Lidar_Composite_DTM_1m&styles&url=https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/lidar-composite-digital-terrain-model-dtm-1m/wms?version%3D1.3.0' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
> Process returned error code 2

I am not well experienced using DTMs.

Comment: The error indicate that you try to use a WMS service to calculate slope, this wont work as WMS are not a "data" format but a "display" format. Try with a WCS service or download the DTM in a suitable format

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I get the same error when using the WCS. I can't see any other formats on offer on the website.

Comment: Try to download the data (https://environment.data.gov.uk/survey) should work better than webservice

Comment: Thank you. I already tried to do this, but the download doesn't seem to be functioning at all - doesn't allow me to draw polygons and uploading a shapefile results in nothing - I have emailed Defra about it